# Using Ubuntu Server To Refresh Google Sheets in the Background

Tags: server, google-drive, background-process

I don't even know if this is possible, but I'm new to Ubuntu and figured this would be the place to ask.

I have a few web apps on my phone that I have set up using data from a Google Sheet (using a service called GlideApps). The problem is, certain functions only update while the Google Sheet is open on a computer [i.e. NOW()]. Is there a way to have an instance of Google Sheets running and/or refreshing the spreadsheet on a constant basis using Ubuntu Server? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Am I missing an easier solution using scripts & triggers, or is this possible with my Ubuntu server?

Comment: does [this reference](https://hevodata.com/learn/google-sheets-to-sql-server/) provide any possible clues?

Comment: Yes Here is how to do that https://developers.google.com/sheets/api You need to create an API to communicate with your sheet.